# PySide2 signal instances and emit function as regular python function arguments

Tags: python, pyside2, qtgui

I have a PySide2 application that runs mostly well. However, from time to time, it exits itself without any error (stdout, stderr are empty, even when run from terminal - tried everything) while a worker thread sends updates to the GUI thread via signals.

To emit these signals however, I'm doing it in a way such that my libraries can just take callbacks and not even know they are actually emitting signals, and I was wondering whether this could be a potential source of crashes:

Gui code:

```
from mylib import do_threaded_work

MyClass(QObject):
    sig = Signal(int)
    # ... proper initialization and connection of self.sig to a QProgressBar setValue slot
    def on_some_button_pressed(self):
        threading.Thread(target=do_threaded_work, args=(self.sig.emit,), daemon=True).start()
```

mylib.py dummy code:

```
do_threaded_work(on_progress):
    i = 0
    while (True):
        # ... do some work
        on_progress(i)
        i = min(100, i + 1)
```

As you see, I'm directly passing the *emit* function of my signal instance to the library, that calls it and thus should emit the signal. **Is it OK to do that?**

Sometimes, I pass the signal object *self.sig* as argument instead of *self.sig.emit*, then call *argument.emit(...)* in the library code. I assume it has the same effect?

The reason I ask is because I didn't find any counter argument stating not to do this in PySide2, and the official documentation on signal and slots is [quite light here](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Signals_and_Slots).

You guys have any input on this? Thanks!

Comment: please provide a [mre]